# "Object Oriented" Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define-record-type car-ivars
       (fields efficiency (mutable gas-in-tank)))
(define-record-type car-methods
       (fields drive! get-gas-in-tank refuel))
(define refuel (lambda (c g) ((car-methods-refuel c) g)))
(define get-gas-level
       (lambda (c) ((car-methods-get-gas-in-tank c))))
(define drive!
       (lambda (c distance) ((car-methods-drive! c) distance)))

(define make-car
       (lambda (efficiency)
         (let ([car1 (make-car-ivars efficiency 0)])
           (let ([set-gas-level!
                   (lambda (gas) (car-ivars-gas-in-tank-set! car1 gas))]
                 [gas-level
                   (lambda () ((car-ivars-gas-in-tank car1)))])
             (make-car-methods
               ;;drive!
               (lambda (distance)
                (set-gas-level!
                 (- (get-gas-level)
                 (/ efficiency distance)))
               ;;get-gas-level
               (get-gas-levels)
               ;;refuel
               (lambda (gas1)
                 (set-gas-level!
                    (+ (get-gas-level) gas1)))))))))
```

Ok, so I have this code. When i try to run my test case of

```
(define hybrid (make-car 50))
```

I get an

```
Exception: incorrect number of arguments to #procedure constructor
```

error. And I'm not quite sure where it is coming from.

Comment: it would be quite useful to know which scheme implementation you are using.

Comment: Sebastian's point is good.  I also think we just don't have enough of the code to tell the problem; I suspect this error is actually generated in **make-car-ivars** or **make-car-methods** but that's pure speculation without more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of the `drive` part in `make-car` is missing a right parenthesis, which means that `make-car-methods` only gets one argument.

Re-indenting in Emacs made this pretty obvious:

```
(define make-car
    (lambda (efficiency)
        (let ([car1 (make-car-ivars efficiency 0)])
            (let ([set-gas-level!
                   (lambda (gas) (car-ivars-gas-in-tank-set! car1 gas))]
                  [gas-level
                   (lambda () ((car-ivars-gas-in-tank car1)))])
                (make-car-methods
                 ;;drive!
                 (lambda (distance)
                     (set-gas-level!
                      (- (get-gas-level)
                         (/ efficiency distance)))
                     ;;get-gas-level
                     (get-gas-levels)
                     ;;refuel
                     (lambda (gas1)
                         (set-gas-level!
                          (+ (get-gas-level) gas1)))))))))
```